# Google Sheets automatically terminate cell connections

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a question about Google Sheets.

Example: A number between 1-10 is given in A2 by chance (not just chance, it has many factors).  In cell A1 a name is given that I write down.  There are many names in cells M1 to M100, including the name of A1.  Can I set it so that A2 is automatically in N, after the name of A1.  The number there should then stay there and never change again.

Thanks for your help

Comment: sounds like script job. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: To help us visualize the problem. Kindly include a screenshot of the data and what the output should look like.